# PHP Session Security with the steam web API

Tags: php, security, session, steam-web-api

I know there is a lot of session security questions but I want to know if my specific situation is secure.

In my website the users log in with the steamWebAPI and openID.
It sends me $_SESSION['steamID64'].

I use this steamID64 as full authentification, for instance :

```
if($_SESSION['steamID64'] == [my steam id]) {
    showAdminPanel();
}
```

Can a hacker get my session id and change it in his cookies so the website think he is me ?

Do you have some advices for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session is server side and cannot be changed like cookies. The `session_id` can be stolen by a hacker to tell the server load an specific session for me from server storage.

HTTP_ONLY sessions cannot be stolen by javascript.
It seems to be a good way to login admin and also try `===` that can be more secure this way.